# Is this topology loop free?

Tags: switch, topology, loop

I have the following topology:

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssKfU.png)

I intend to build this network with the PC acting as a DHCP server and multiple IP-enabled custom development boards connected to the switch and some connected to each other for network redundancy. By design, each dev board has two Ethernet ports and retransmits data received on a port to another.

I am worried that the connections between the dev boards could generate loops.

**Can this topology be used without existing the risk of loops appearing? How? Does the switch automatically recognize the connected devices (MACs) and avoids loops?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch uses Layer 2 Spanning Tree Protocol to ensures a loop free topology for any bridged Ethernet network. So if yours IOT device will forward bridge protocol data unit (BPDU) accross, switch will maintain loop free topology. BPDU are transsmited accross local network to detect loops in network topologies. If BPDU won't be forwarded you can possibly have a loop. But effect of STP could be something like on this picture.[image]

So two IOT boards would be able only to talk with DHCP server thru another IOT board.

Comment: Thank you! Since all data received on one port is retransmitted on the other it means the devices will forward BPDUs.

Comment: Thanks again for the edited answer. That is the intended operation. Then, if the connection becomes unavailable, the switch will use the previously unused connection (that marked with red x).

Comment: @CristianM, BPDUs use a special multicast MAC address that the IEEE reserves and has written into the standard that ethernet will not send traffic destined to that address to another interface. Are you absolutely sure that the BPDUs will travel in a circle?

Comment: @RonMaupin The idea was to basically create a bus so that a packet can reach its destination. Can you give me an advice on how to correctly implement this topology? The devices are MSP controllers with RTOS TCP-IP stack.

Comment: @RonMaupin And if a link would break (physical problem) the communication could still be done using a device as a relay, retransmitting the messages.

Comment: You need make sure that frame with destination mac address:01:80:C2:00:00:00 or 01:00:0C:CC:CC:CD (for PVST) is forwarded to other interface.

Comment: @Datagram.Network I don't understand. It seems that your comment is contrary to what Ron Maupin is saying. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Is not, he is saying excatly same but maybe in little diffrent way. So STP works on layer 2 frames. Switches use those multicast frames to check for loops in the network. Devices like PC etc. ignore frames and don't ackonwledge or forward those. You need just make sure that your device would forward BPDU frame from one interface to another. I don't know on what platform is your IOT working so not really sure if it's possible.

Comment: @Datagram.Network The platform will be a custom, with two Ethernet ports, hardware interconnected so that data coming from one is also sent to the other, and a controller with Ethernet interface, connected to the same bus and implementing the TCP-IP stack (I haven't decided, but one solution would be Texas Instruments' TM4C1294 controller running RTOS with TCP-IP stack).